# Как вывести значение ListBoxItem?

Tags: c#, wpf

Извиняюсь, если этот вопрос уже задавали. Честно, ничего такогоо не смог найти.

В моей программе на WPF есть элемент ListBox. Я хочу вывести значение его элемента. Перехват события нажатия на элемент ListBox:

```
public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
{
    private async void mailsListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Emails obj = new Emails();

        await this.ShowMessageAsync(
            obj.mailsList[10], 
            obj.mailsList[mailsListBox.SelectedIndex]);
    }
}
```

Вывод соответствующего значения:

```
public class Emails
{
    public void AddMailsToList()
    {
        MainWindow obj = new MainWindow();
        mailsList.Add(obj.mailsListBox.Items[0].ToString());
        mailsList.Add(obj.mailsListBox.Items[1].ToString());
        mailsList.Add(obj.mailsListBox.Items[2].ToString());
        mailsList.Add(obj.mailsListBox.Items[3].ToString());
        mailsList.Add(obj.mailsListBox.Items[4].ToString());
        mailsList.Add(obj.mailsListBox.Items[5].ToString());
        mailsList.Add(obj.mailsListBox.Items[6].ToString());
        mailsList.Add(obj.mailsListBox.Items[7].ToString());
        mailsList.Add(obj.mailsListBox.Items[8].ToString());
        mailsList.Add(obj.mailsListBox.Items[9].ToString());

        // title of the mail
        mailsList.Add("You have new message");
    }
}
```

Но вместе с сообщением выводится ненужная системная информация:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как этого избежать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы должны делать не так. Информация, которую вы пытаетесь вывести, не предназначена для показа пользователю.

Правильно делать следующим образом. Вы не должны работать напрямую с визуальными контролами, у вас же не WinForms. Определите типизированный список элементов (объектов), которые вы хотите показать, и передайте его как `ItemsSource` из вашей view model'и. Опросите текущий элемент этого списка как `SelectedItem`. Имея типизированный объект, вытаскивайте из него нужную информацию.

(Если для вас буквосочетание MVVM пока ничего не означает, срочно читайте про него!)